# Unknown module(s) in QT: webkit

Tags: c++, qt, webkit, qtwebkit

Added `QT += network webkit` and I tried just `QT += webkit` to the .pro solution file and ran qmake from inside the QtCreator and got this error:

```
error: Unknown module(s) in QT: webkit
```

I really need to make use of these includes:

```
#include <QWebView>
#include <QUrl>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: When you post a question, the editor/markup language (a variant of markdown) offers several formatting options.

Comment: Seems like you have Qt without webkit. Where did you get Qt from? Did you compile it on your own?

Comment: But it finds webkit if you leave `network` in that line?

Comment: Thanks @phresnel  but it does not find with or without network

Comment: @KamilKlimek I got the beta version (like the latest release) from their website: http://developer.qt.nokia.com/downloads#qt-creator

Comment: Did you install all Qt frameworks?

Comment: @KamilKlimek I just installed the QT beta SDK installer, I thought that just did install all the frameworks, if not how do I install them?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you say you installed the beta version I suppose you installed Qt version 5. In that case webkit module does not exist anymore. You need webkitwidgets:

```
QT += webkitwidgets
```

That will add the module needed to use QWebView. QUrl is in the core module, so you don't need the network module.